# Extjs4, which(what) is better way to create Extjs object that render to html element

Tags: extjs4

```
<div id="wrap">
    <table id="listTable"></table>
</div>
```

Case #1)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.define("testClass", {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
        title: 'Hello',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: { html: 'AAAA' },
        renderTo : 'listTable'
    }, function () {
        var cls = new testClass();
    });
});// end onReady
```

Case #2)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Hello',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: { html: 'AAAA' },
        renderTo: 'listTable'
    });
});// end onReady
```

Or do you have a better idea? Please advice me.

Comment: Where to call Ext.onReady ? In app.js or Viewport.js? Plus are you using a viewport or not while layouting your application using renderTo's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second is correct. Why define a class if you're only going to use it once?

Comment: Because, I heard define is better for performance, http://jsperf.com/extjs-create-vs-define-create , but most example and tutorial uses create, even Sencha example code too. @.@